# Client sends ABORT in response to SCTP INIT ACK

Tags: sctp

I am working on telcom product and using a tool to create SCTP connection with peer node. I see that client sends INIT to server, Server sends back INIT-ACK. Now client is generating ABORT to this message. I wonder what might have gone wrong.
[image]

Comment: It would be worth sharing content of all three chunks here: INIT, INIT_ACK and ABORT.

Answer (score 1):

There are Cause Parameters in ABORT chunk that can help in informing the reason for the abort.